# Not getting the expected page after log out and login back.

Tags: angular, routes

I have implemented lazy load routing module in current angular 6 project. 
I have created few sample components.
I am getting the following behaviour in routing.

1. Suppose I login to my admin account (used REST api for login.)
2. Control-tower-alerts is my default home page. It navigates perfect for the first time .
3. Now I navigate to contracts- alerts , It navigates perfect .
4. Now I navigate to login Page and sign in again. The page is redirected to default home page , but contracts- alerts is active on the side bar, which is not expected . any help is appreciated.

thanks 
1. 
[image: This is my expected output after login in 2nd time]

2. [image: This is the login page]
3. [image: This is what i am getting]

This is my code

1. Route for Contracts .

   ```
   const routes: Routes = [{
     path: '',
     component: ContractsComponent,
     children: [{
       path: 'contracts-alerts',
       component: ContractsAlertsComponent,
     },
     {
       path: 'contracts-add',
       component: ContractsAddComponent,
     }, {
       path: 'contracts-manage',
       component: ContractsManageComponent,
     }, {
       path: 'contracts-trend',
       component: ContractsTrendComponent,
     }],
   }];

   @NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
     exports: [RouterModule],
   })

   export class ContractsRoutingModule { }

   export const routedComponents = [
     ContractsComponent,
     ContractsAlertsComponent,
     ContractsManageComponent,
     ContractsTrendComponent,
     ContractsAddComponent,
     ContractsManageDetailsComponent
   ];
   ```
2. Code for contracts module

   @NgModule({
       imports: [ThemeModule, ContractsRoutingModule, Ng2SmartTableModule],
       declarations: [...routedComponents],
     })
3. code for main routing

   const routes: Routes = [{path: '',
        component: MainComponent,

   ```
    children: [{
      path: 'control-tower',
      loadChildren: './control-tower/control-tower.module#ControlTowerModule',
    }, {
      path: 'contracts',
      loadChildren: './contracts/contracts.module#ContractsModule',
    },
    {
      path: 'orders',
      loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule',
    }, {
      path: 'shipments',
      loadChildren: './shipments/shipments.module#ShipmentsModule',
    }, {
      path: 'planning',
      loadChildren: './planning/planning.module#PlanningModule',
    }, {
      path: 'finance',
             loadChildren: './finance/finance.module#FinanceModule',
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'control-tower',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    }],
   ```

   }]; 
          @NgModule({
            imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
            exports: [RouterModule],
      })
       export class MainRoutingModule implements OnDestroy { 
       ngOnDestroy() { 
        } 
      }
4. Main - Menu

   ```
       export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
       {
           title: 'Control Tower',
           icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
           home: true,
           children: [
               {
                   title: 'Alerts',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/control-tower/control-tower-alerts',
               },
               {
                   title: 'Dashboard',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/control-tower/control-tower-dashboard',
               },
               {
                   title: 'Trend',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/control-tower/control-tower-trend',
               }]
       },
       {
           title: 'Contracts',
           icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
           children: [
               {
                   title: 'Alerts',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/contracts/contracts-alerts'
               },
               {
                   title: 'Manage',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/contracts/contracts-manage'
               },
               {
                   title: 'Trend',
                   icon: 'control-tower-menu-icon',
                   link: '/main/contracts/contracts-trend'
               }]
       },
   ```

Comment: You have included a lot of code but none of that shows how you highlighted the contract alerts. The trouble will be there.

Comment: @Pes figured it out, there was a issue in login authentication , i had to use authorize the components, I used canLoad instead of canActivate to Authorize, when using Lazy Load. Previously,when I logged out  it was redirecting back in , even when there was no token registered.